# Sync to Async Django ORM model iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, python-asyncio

I have a class `User` which needs to be iterated at the asyncio script.

What is the correct way to convert `User.objcets.iterator()` to async iterator with `__aiter__`...?

Comment: Does the returned iterator block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create such iterator using async generator(it has **aiter** function):

```
async def sync_to_async(iterator):
    for i in iterator:
        yield i
```

Also output from console

```
>>> it = Chat.objects.iterator()
>>> ait = sync_to_async(it)
>>> dir(ait)
['__aiter__', '__anext__', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'aclose', 'ag_await', 'ag_code', 'ag_frame', 'ag_running', 'asend', 'athrow']
```

Comment: It is not work with:  django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 4.1, you may now use `User.objects.aiterator()`